# highlight matching brackets (parenthesis) in vba editor

Tags: excel, vba

I went through most of the tool bar, but couldn't find this option.
Is there a way to highlight matching () in the excel vba editor?

Thanks

Comment: http://rubberduckvba.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can press Strg + F and search in your project for the matching brackets `()`

Comment: what's `Strg` stand for?